# Find highest number with loops

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, max

I'm trying to write a program that finds out which number was the highest after input of several numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("...Find the highest number... (0 to exit)\n\n");
    double num1;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &num1);

        if (num1 == 0)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this? I'm not sure how to solve it. I don't want to create 1000 variables and store each number, if the user decides to enter 1000 numbers fx.

Comment: Define two variables, `currentNum` and `max`.  If `currentNum > max` rewrite `max` value.

Comment: Just keep track of the largest.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a variable to track the highest value inputted, for example you could add this after the if statment

```
if (num1 > highest) {
   highest = num1;
}
```

And add this to the declaration of num1,

```
double num1, highest = 0;
```

Comment: You should initialize `highest` to `-DBL_MAX` unless only positive values are allowed.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Oh yeah i forgot about that, thx for adding that

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare two variables. The first one for example of the type `int` that will indicate whether the user entered at least one number not equal to 0.0. And the second variable will store the current largest number.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    double largest;

    printf( "...Find the highest number... (0 to exit)\n\n" );

    int empty = 1;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        double x;

        printf( "Enter a number: " );

        if ( scanf(  "%lf", &x ) != 1 || x == 0.0 ) break;

        if ( empty || largest < x )
        {
            empty = 0;
            largest = x;
        }
    }

    if ( !empty )
    {
        printf( "\nThe largest number is %.1f\n", largest );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "\nYou have not entered any number unequal to 0" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look for example like

```
...Find the highest number... (0 to exit)

Enter a number: 3.3 
Enter a number: 4.4 
Enter a number: 1.1 
Enter a number: 2.2 
Enter a number: 9.9 
Enter a number: 5.5
Enter a number: 0

The largest number is 9.9
```

Comment: x is not initialized

Comment: @MickaelB. You are right!:)

Comment: Also you might want to add error handling, if the user type something else than a number the scanf will be stuck

Comment: @MickaelB. It is not me who should do this. It is the author of the question might do this.:) I have just demonstrated an approach to the assignment.

Comment: He is a beginner and since you've started an answer you could make it complete with good practices.

Comment: @MickaelB. For a beginner it is a very good program.:)

Comment: Nitpick: `empty` could be done away with if `largest` initialized to `-DBL_MAX`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits In this case if the user entered nothing are you going to output DBL_MAX?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Nothing is not a number.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Do you mean NaN? And what will you do if the program will be rewritten for integers?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No.  By "if the user entered nothing" I thought you meant just press [ENTER].

Comment: @FiddlingBits Nothing means nothing.:)

Comment: Just a nitpick... nothing more.